# IBM-MQ Create MQ Destination

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

Using spring boot and IBM MQ i need to send message to MQ.

In My Spring boot application i have registered `MQQueueConnectionFactory` as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        logger.info("init completed...");
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        try {
            queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            queueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            queueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            queueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            queueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return queueConnectionFactory;
    }

}
```

And i have destination resolver as below.

```
 @Component
 public class IBMWebSphereMqDestinationResolver extends 
  DynamicDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver {

@Override
public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
    Destination destination = super.resolveDestinationName(session, destinationName, pubSubDomain);
    if (destination instanceof MQDestination) {
        MQDestination mqDestination = (MQDestination) destination;
    }
    return destination;
}

}
```

I am using JmsTemplate to send message to MQ.

```
@Service
public class MqServiceImpl implements MqService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MQDestination destination;

    @Handler
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String textMessage) {
        logger.info("textMessage {} ", textMessage);
        logger.info("destination {}  ", destination);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, textMessage);
    }

}
```

However when i try to start the application i am getting `MQDestination' that could not be found.`

```
service.impl.MqServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination' in your configuration.
```

Shouldn't spring try to call DestinationResolver ?

If not how do i register destination for IBM MQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an `DestinationResolver` bean, but injecting an `MQDestination` bean. This is why you get the error. You should inject the `DestinationResolver` and call `setDestinationResolver` on the `JmsTemplate`.

But the `JmsTemplate` resolves the destinations dynamically. This works as well:

```
public void sendMessage(String textMessage) {
    String destination = "MY.QUEUE";
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, textMessage);
}
```